# Using regrouped variable of django template in javascript

Tags: javascript, django

From my view function, I have sent some data to django template. In the template, data are grouped using regroup method.

```
{% regroup data|dictsort:"month" by month as data_month_list %}
```

Is there any way to use the data_month_list in javascript?

Comment: How do you want to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Actually it was simple. At first I was trying to assign the value directly to my js code. Later I declared a variable in django template, assigned the data_month_list in the variable and used it in my js code. Now it works.